# VBA excel - use value from combobox in other code

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

So i have a macro `code1` that do stuff with the value selected by user. Currently the selection is made thanks to simple data validation (user can only select item from the list). After the selection is made, user presses `button1` and a `code1` macro is performed.

Instead of data validation i would like the user to first press mentioned `button1` and then select an item from the `combobox1` list that appeard as `userform1`, and then use that value in code.

I have found some simple coding for combobox and userform. This works by itself, but i dont know how to implement this into my `code1`

Here is the code i found for combobox and userform

`Private Sub ComboBox1_Click() 
    Unload UserForm1 
End Sub 
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate() 
    Dim fruit As String 
    fruit = ComboBox1.Value 
   End Sub 
Private Sub Userform_Initialize() 
    Dim fruits As Variant 
    ReDim fruits(4) 
    fruits = Array("banana", "mango", "orange", "berry") 
    ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 1 
    ComboBox1.List() = fruits 
End Sub`

My `code1` just takes the value from the cell with data validation and do stuff with it. Id like it to take the value from combobox instead. Putting the `ComboBox1.Value` or `fruit` instead of `worksheets("Sheet1").range("a1").value` in my `code1` doesnt help.

I dont know how to merge those codes together.

Can you help?

Comment: Let me clarify, you want a button that when gets clicked shows a form with the combobox , and when a value of that cb its selected the code executes ?

Comment: If your `Sub code1()` is not in the `Userform (Code)` window, you can get the value of the combobox by `UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value`.

Comment: @Tyeler - once the form is unloaded, the values won't be available any more

Comment: @YowE3K Oh that first Sub..... I somehow didn't even read that.. you're right, I assumed too much lol..

Comment: @jsanchezs Exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your UserForm1 code module have the code you currently set up, except get rid of the declaration of the variable `fruit`, i.e.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()
    fruit = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    Dim fruits As Variant
    ReDim fruits(4)
    fruits = Array("banana", "mango", "orange", "berry")
    ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 1
    ComboBox1.List() = fruits
End Sub
```

In your main code module (Module1?) include code such as:

```
Option Explicit

Public fruit As String

Sub code1()
    UserForm1.Show
    MsgBox "You selected " & fruit
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click()
    code1
End Sub
```

By declaring `fruit` in your code module (as `Public`), your userform will be able to update its value, and your macro will be able to read the value.

Comment: @ YowE3K It worked. BTW how do i format posts here so i can have a vba code in the greyed out field with colored fonts like you do?

Comment: @mm90 - The easiest way to format code is to paste the code in, making sure that there is at least one blank line before and after it, then highlight the entire section and press Ctrl-K.  (It just shifts it to the right so that there are at least 4 spaces at the start of each line.  So the harder way is to just manually insert the 4 spaces.)  And to enclose small snippets (in comments etc) so that they look like `this` just put ` marks before and after them.